# Array of objects with constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, constructor

I have class named `Novel`. I can declare array of objects as mentioned below:

```
Novel obj;
```

but problem is `Novel` has constructor which I want to be called for all indexes of array how can I do that. I tried following but it does not work.

```
Novel obj(i,n)[2];
```

Comment: Basically, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a proper container that uses dynamic allocation to defer construction of individual elements.

```
std::vector<Novel> objs(2, Novel(i,n));
```

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the C++ language does not provide that capability. Arrays are allocated, but by default they are not initialised at all. If they are allocated in static storage they get filled with zeros; you can give a brace-initialiser; and you can provide a default constructor to initialise each value. What you cannot do is initialise an array with any other constructor.

To achieve a similar effect you have to approach the problem from a different angle. Basically, you can:
- write a macro or template that both allocates an array and calls a constructor on each element under the covers, or
- create an object with array semantics, which can initialise itself any way you like.

The built in collection classes are usually the best solution. For example, std::vector provides fill, range and copy constructors as well as array semantics. One of the other answers provides an example, but there are several ways to do it.

```
std::vector<Novel> objs(2, Novel(i,n));
```

It's not an array, but it should do what you need.